# How to exclude a wp page and rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache

1. I have a wordpress site with a page named `domain.com/dogs`.  I want to change that exact page to a regular blank white page that I can type text or html in and be able to turn this feature on and off easy enough manually.
2. What will the name of the file be that I'm replacing it with?  `domain.com/dogs` or `domain.com/dogs.php` etc?  Remember I want it to be EXACTLY the same url.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Rephrase. I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually find the file that you're talking about on the server or
use GoogleChrome: Right-click(on page)>inspect element > Network (tab).... where you will find the file. The file name and extension will be shown.

Once you know the page extensions you will know what to put:

domain.com/

NOTE: This will work unless there is a masking script that rewrites the url of address bar.

Then you have to go into the server and edit the file itself, and delete all of the contents of the page. Then you can start a new page with the standard HTML headers and include the text you want. NOTE: MAKE SURE THAT YOU SAVE THE FILE WITH THE SAME NAME AND EXTENSION TO THE SAME LOCATION, this will do what I think you're trying to achieve.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Under networks Im not seeing any files.  Its pretty blank---> http://prntscr.com/6owgsw .  How would I go about editing the file itself?  I duno where to find it.  Can you provide some more steps?  (: